# Cannot connect to VSFTPD on port 21

Tags: ubuntu, ftp, vsftpd

I have installed `vsftpd` on my `Linux Ubuntu 21.04` instance using the following:

```
sudo apt-get install vsftpd
```

I have enabled FTP in my `ufw` firewall using the following:

```
sudo ufw allow ftp
```

My `/etc/vsftpd.conf` file contains the following:

```
# Example config file /etc/vsftpd.conf
#
# The default compiled in settings are fairly paranoid. This sample file
# loosens things up a bit, to make the ftp daemon more usable.
# Please see vsftpd.conf.5 for all compiled in defaults.
#
# READ THIS: This example file is NOT an exhaustive list of vsftpd options.
# Please read the vsftpd.conf.5 manual page to get a full idea of vsftpd's
# capabilities.
#
#
# Run standalone?  vsftpd can run either from an inetd or as a standalone
# daemon started from an initscript.
listen=YES
#
# This directive enables listening on IPv6 sockets. By default, listening
# on the IPv6 "any" address (::) will accept connections from both IPv6
# and IPv4 clients. It is not necessary to listen on *both* IPv4 and IPv6
# sockets. If you want that (perhaps because you want to listen on specific
# addresses) then you must run two copies of vsftpd with two configuration
# files.
listen_ipv6=NO
#
# Allow anonymous FTP? (Disabled by default).
anonymous_enable=NO
#
# Uncomment this to allow local users to log in.
local_enable=YES
#
# Uncomment this to enable any form of FTP write command.
write_enable=YES
#
# Default umask for local users is 077. You may wish to change this to 022,
# if your users expect that (022 is used by most other ftpd's)
#local_umask=022
#
# Uncomment this to allow the anonymous FTP user to upload files. This only
# has an effect if the above global write enable is activated. Also, you will
# obviously need to create a directory writable by the FTP user.
#anon_upload_enable=YES
#
# Uncomment this if you want the anonymous FTP user to be able to create
# new directories.
#anon_mkdir_write_enable=YES
#
# Activate directory messages - messages given to remote users when they
# go into a certain directory.
dirmessage_enable=YES
#
# If enabled, vsftpd will display directory listings with the time
# in  your  local  time  zone.  The default is to display GMT. The
# times returned by the MDTM FTP command are also affected by this
# option.
use_localtime=YES
#
# Activate logging of uploads/downloads.
xferlog_enable=YES
#
# Make sure PORT transfer connections originate from port 20 (ftp-data).
connect_from_port_20=YES
#
# If you want, you can arrange for uploaded anonymous files to be owned by
# a different user. Note! Using "root" for uploaded files is not
# recommended!
#chown_uploads=YES
#chown_username=whoever
#
# You may override where the log file goes if you like. The default is shown
# below.
#xferlog_file=/var/log/vsftpd.log
#
# If you want, you can have your log file in standard ftpd xferlog format.
# Note that the default log file location is /var/log/xferlog in this case.
#xferlog_std_format=YES
#
# You may change the default value for timing out an idle session.
#idle_session_timeout=600
#
# You may change the default value for timing out a data connection.
#data_connection_timeout=120
#
# It is recommended that you define on your system a unique user which the
# ftp server can use as a totally isolated and unprivileged user.
#nopriv_user=ftpsecure
#
# Enable this and the server will recognise asynchronous ABOR requests. Not
# recommended for security (the code is non-trivial). Not enabling it,
# however, may confuse older FTP clients.
#async_abor_enable=YES
#
# By default the server will pretend to allow ASCII mode but in fact ignore
# the request. Turn on the below options to have the server actually do ASCII
# mangling on files when in ASCII mode.
# Beware that on some FTP servers, ASCII support allows a denial of service
# attack (DoS) via the command "SIZE /big/file" in ASCII mode. vsftpd
# predicted this attack and has always been safe, reporting the size of the
# raw file.
# ASCII mangling is a horrible feature of the protocol.
#ascii_upload_enable=YES
#ascii_download_enable=YES
#
# You may fully customise the login banner string:
#ftpd_banner=Welcome to blah FTP service.
#
# You may specify a file of disallowed anonymous e-mail addresses. Apparently
# useful for combatting certain DoS attacks.
#deny_email_enable=YES
# (default follows)
#banned_email_file=/etc/vsftpd.banned_emails
#
# You may restrict local users to their home directories.  See the FAQ for
# the possible risks in this before using chroot_local_user or
# chroot_list_enable below.
chroot_local_user=YES
#
# You may specify an explicit list of local users to chroot() to their home
# directory. If chroot_local_user is YES, then this list becomes a list of
# users to NOT chroot().
# (Warning! chroot'ing can be very dangerous. If using chroot, make sure that
# the user does not have write access to the top level directory within the
# chroot)
#chroot_local_user=YES
#chroot_list_enable=YES
# (default follows)
#chroot_list_file=/etc/vsftpd.chroot_list
#
# You may activate the "-R" option to the builtin ls. This is disabled by
# default to avoid remote users being able to cause excessive I/O on large
# sites. However, some broken FTP clients such as "ncftp" and "mirror" assume
# the presence of the "-R" option, so there is a strong case for enabling it.
#ls_recurse_enable=YES
#
# Customization
#
# Some of vsftpd's settings don't fit the filesystem layout by
# default.
#
# This option should be the name of a directory which is empty.  Also, the
# directory should not be writable by the ftp user. This directory is used
# as a secure chroot() jail at times vsftpd does not require filesystem
# access.
secure_chroot_dir=/var/run/vsftpd/empty
#
# This string is the name of the PAM service vsftpd will use.
pam_service_name=vsftpd
#
# This option specifies the location of the RSA certificate to use for SSL
# encrypted connections.
rsa_cert_file=/etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem
rsa_private_key_file=/etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key
ssl_enable=NO

#
# Uncomment this to indicate that vsftpd use a utf8 filesystem.
#utf8_filesystem=YES

user_sub_token=$USER
local_root=/home/$USER/ftp_user

userlist_enable=YES
userlist_file=/etc/vsftpd.user_list
userlist_deny=NO
```

I have added my intended user account `ftpuser` to `/etc/vsftpd.user_list`. The following is contained in the output of `netstat -tanp`:

```
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:27017           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      939/docker-proxy
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:21              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      585614/vsftpd
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.53:53           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      582461/systemd-reso
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      581200/sshd: /usr/s
```

The above seems to indicate that `vsftpd` is listening on port 21 as it should be. However, I cannot connect to it using `WinSCP` on port 21 with the FTP protocol. However, what is strange is that I can connect on port 22 with the SFTP protocol.

I should also mention that I previously did have `vsftpd` installed and configured for SFTP. I did `sudo apt-get purge vsftpd` and have been trying to reinstall since.

**Edit** Even when I run `ftp localhost` I receive the error message : `ftp: connect: Connection timed out`

These are the steps I have now taken.

Install VSFTPD

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install vsftpd
sudo service vsftpd status
```

Configure firewall

```
sudo ufw allow 20/tcp
sudo ufw allow 21/tcp
sudo ufw allow 40000:50000/tcp
sudo ufw allow 990/tcp
sudo ufw allow openssh
sudo ufw enable
sudo ufw status
```

Create ftpuser and directories

```
sudo adduser ftpuser
sudo mkdir /home/ftpuser/ftp
sudo chown nobody:nogroup /home/ftpuser/ftp
sudo chmod a-w /home/ftpuser/ftp
sudo mkdir /home/ftpuser/ftp/files
sudo chown ftpuser:ftpuser /home/ftpuser/ftp/files
```

Setup VSFTPD configuration

```
sudo nano /etc/vsftpd.conf
```

With the following entries

```
listen=YES
listen_ipv6=NO
anonymos_enable=NO
local_enable=YES
write_enable=YES
local_mask=022
dirmessage_enable=YES
use_localtime=YES
xferlog_enable=YES
connect_from_port_20=YES
chroot_local_user=YES
secure_chroot_dir=/var/run/vsftpd/empty
pam_service_name=vsftpd
force_dot_files=YES
pasv_min_port=40000
pasv_max_port=50000

user_sub_token=$USER
local_root=/home/$USER/ftp
```

Restart the VSFTPD to have changes take effect

```
sudo systemctl restart vsftpd.service
```

Try connecting with Filezilla and WinSCP. Neither worked for FTP port 21. However, just as previously, I was able to connect via SFTP on port 22.

Comment: Why are your pasv ports so high? A port number xant be bigger then 65535? (Maybe a typi in your config? It doesnt match what you have for the firewall)

Comment: Thanks. That was a typo in my config file which I did just fix. However, `ftp localhost` or connecting externally with `WinSCP` did not work. I also did implement `listen=YES` as per your below suggestion. However, these two changes did not fix the issue.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is your config is wrong. The first line is

```
  listen=no
```

Surely that needs to be yes - as your firewall entries are for IPV4?  (Also, check your port numbers as per my comment)

Comment: Thank you. I changed that entry to `listen=YES` and fixed the port numbers. However, I still cannot connect with `ftp localhost` or `WinSCP`.

Answer (score 0):

I reinstalled Ubuntu 21.04 and followed the steps in this tutorial : https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-vsftpd-for-a-user-s-directory-on-ubuntu-18-04, and it is working as expected.